Google Vertex AI - Agent Builder - Data store not returning the FAQ documents
I have recently started using the Agent builder and setup the tool. The tool has 3 data stores, one is website and as i tested the Agent (included the snippet) the Tool function is able to search correctly the query from Data Store. However, for FAQ documents, even if i am querying the exact question the snippet is returning empty. Now i don't know any solution how to debug or correct this behavior. Any pointers are appreciated.
I have tried detaching and reattaching the data store, purging all the FAQ documents and reimporting them, but its not working. Some FAQ documents are getting searched but rest are not.
P.S i have posted the same here as well but no response yet

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ensure that you follow exactly the structure outlined for the FAQ CSV here https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/vertex/docs/concept/data-store#structured
Then you can check in the Data Store UI that each FAQ entry is showing up as Document. If that is the case, check your Dialogflow CX configuration and ensure the Data Store is configured and you have a fulfilment like $request.knowledge.answers[0] configured. Then query an exact question from the FAQ using the simulator and check the debugInformation provided by the simulator.
